# Enhanced Inbox with Recent Activity

Tags: feature-request, notifications, top-bar, global-inbox

**Problem:**

There's no quick way to navigate back to the last question(s) or answers you posted if you navigate away from them, especially if there has been no activity. You may be able to click backwards in the current tab sufficient times or navigate to the tab you had it open.

Allowing easier access to questions without activity may encourage appropriate modifying (editing or even deleting if a solution has been found). Bad questions that should be edited are the ones likely to be subject to less activity.

This problem is also prevalent if active on more than one SE site. I know that you can go to the respective profile/activity page, but this is still a little tedious.

[image]

**Possible Solutions:**

- Add entries for recent questions and answers to the inbox. These could be (automatically) cleared when there is any activity (upvotes, comments etc) on the same question to avoid excessive clutter.
- Create a new tab for recent activity and redefine the purposes for the inbox and achievements respectively.

Comment: I like the idea, but the current dropdown is good. Don't clutter it. The profile page is just one step away.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see your activity across different sites then you can see that on the [activity page on your network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/1082905/mikefoxtrot?tab=activity). There are various ways to refine this via the sub tabs there e.g. to show posts only.

There is a network profile link on your [site profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/307086/mikefoxtrot).

[image: network profile link]

Comment: Awesome, I thought there would be a one stop shop for something like this. I overlooked that there was a general page.

Comment: Huh, looks like you can't "hotlink" to posts only. [This](http://stackexchange.com/users/activity/1082905?page=1&filter=posts) shows raw HTML. :/

Comment: @ShadowWizard Indeed, I was trying to do that too. I've [created a feature request for it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267770/allow-hotlinking-to-network-activity-areas).

Answer (score 1):

Really can't see the gain here.

The last post is **one** (1) click away anyway, in the [profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current):

> [image]

Since we also need to click the inbox icon to open it anyway, there's no gain whatsoever. Adding those items will just clutter the inbox.

Comment: What gets me is that this is only efficient on a site-specific basis. Navigating between Aviation SE and Engineering SE that are fairly related is more tedious.

Comment: For this we have such thing in the top bar, making any site we want one click away too: http://i.stack.imgur.com/dCPRL.png (the "YOUR COMMUNITIES" part is totally editable :))