# Allow hotlinking to network activity filters

Tags: feature-request, network-profile

If you go to your site profile and then select activity you can refine your search in various ways e.g. [just posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/188189/robert-longson?tab=activity&sort=posts) or [just comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/188189/robert-longson?tab=activity&sort=comments)

If you try this on your [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity) then selecting any of the refinements does not change the URL so it's not possible to hotlink to those areas.

[image: network profile]

The usecase I have is [showing this feature to a user in an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267769/188189) which I currently have to describe rather than providing a link straight to the feature.